# Unable to create drivers/xxx/xxx/xxx.c (protocol error)?

Tags: git, ubuntu, protocols, vmware

When I am checking out I am getting the following error.

```
error: unable to create file drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nvkm/subdev/i2c/aux.c (Protocol error)
error: unable to create file drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nvkm/subdev/i2c/aux.h (Protocol error)
Checking out files: 100% (53018/53018), done.
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'origin/android-hikey-linaro-4.4'.
```

I am using Ubuntun in the vmware and windows as host os.
I am accessing windows partition in the vmware ubuntu and trying to checkout to a new branch and I am getting that error.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?
I am accessing the windows driver by sharing that in the vmware using shared folder feature.

Comment: What does `git status` say and what was the exact command `git checkout...?`

Comment: "Protocol error" means that your Linux box asked the host VM system to do something and either the host (your Windows system) said "no, that's a protocol violation", or the host's answer was unintelligible (so that the Linux system said "I see an error in my client/host protocol". Either way it means your Linux and Windows box aren't talking to each other any more. Git cannot do anything about this; you must solve this at the Linux or Windows OS/protocol level.

Comment: @torek How to solve this? Is there anything that I can do?

Comment: @Christoph git status showing some random info related to the deleted file and untracked files.   git checkout -b hikey-4.4

Comment: @AQU: I have no idea; I don't "do" Windows.